Why mutation observer is not working for some pages once page is fully loaded - Chrome Extension
Puzzled by this problem.
I am trying to execute this simple code which just checks the changes of attributes on my specific created element. It works fine when the page is in loading state but once I reload page and wait for it to be fully loaded, then it doesn't matter which piece of new code I try, it just doesn't work. I also realized it works fine for many other sites but not for this specific website.
For context, this specific website is medical service provider, it uses angular probably and uses state concepts like history.pushState etc without reloading the page.
function initiateObserverListener() { 
const dataHolder = document.createElement("div"); 
dataHolder.setAttribute("id", "extension-dataHolder"); 
document.body.appendChild(dataHolder);

// Create and set up the observer
const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    console.log("Here");
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        console.log("Mutation executed: ", mutation.type);
        if (mutation.type === "attributes" && mutation.attributeName === "base64data") {
            console.log("in mutation");
            console.log(mutation.target.getAttribute("base64data"));
        }
    });
});

observer.observe(document.documentElement, {
    attributes: true,
    childList:true,
});

dataHolder.setAttribute("base64data", "exampleBase64Data");
initiateObserverListener();



It's unclear what happens since your code works on other sites. Such problems can be solved by debugging the script in the built-in devtools. 2) There's no need to observe the entire document, you can observe the dataHolder element directly. 3) How is this element changed and where?


@woxxom I changed the element attribute based on the intercepted PDF response. Now after debugging I realized the site uses zone.js which replaces all of built in apis, but the problem is that I still have to execute certain scripts on page context level which is restricting me to do since all native apis are replaced with zone.js apis.
Content script works fine because it runs in isolated mode. What options are available to tackle this out from the context of extension?

Use CustomEvent for messaging data instead of an element.

@woxxom Thanks alot, so that solves the issue for the mutation observer, right also is there any way to prevent zone.js from reflecting new state if button clicks anything? I mean I only want the functionalities to be executed by clicking that button which are the site owns but not the current state to be lost somehow.
Overriding window.history methods do not work either. Is there solution from extension?

Overriding must be done in the MAIN world.

I did overriding direct in browser console but still doesn't work. Although the window history state are frozen but somehow the content on button clicking is rendering(page URL isn't changed).

It should be overridden in a content script running at document_start in the MAIN world.
